# SSD and removable swap with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, ssd, swap

I have seen a lot of questions and articles about Ubuntu and SSDs. I have got confused and I am really worry about my investment in a SSD.

I got some data about expressions such as Trim and I need to be specific for Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Does Ubuntu 16.04 make such trim automatically?
2. Do I need any extra settings that improves my SSD performance and , in the same time, improving its life time?

Additionally, I will not mount a `swap` partition on the SSD, but I will mount it to an USB memory stick because I will need hibernate to be available and to save the SSD from excessive writing.

For that removable `swap`, after setting the memory stick as a swap partition, what if I have decided to temporarily unmount it?  Should I have to re configure it again to work as a swap when I mount it again?

Comment: I do most of these. https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd Primarily noatime and mounting some tmp folders in RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fear of failing disks is perhaps as old as the time disk were developed. That is why backup techniques were developed shortly after. At first to magnetic media, CD/DVD and later to disks as they became cheaper. Techniques like RAID were developed short time later to further prevent loss of data. There are many articles stating the latest generation of SSD's can handle hundereds of terrabytes, even close to petabyes read and written before they start showing signs of deterioration.
(http://www.pcworld.com/article/2856052/grueling-endurance-test-blows-away-ssd-durability-fears.html)
But yes, just as normal disks also SSD's can fail but they will not just pop-off like a light bulb. Your PC will start complaining about bad sectors or I/O errors first, so you still can copy data from it.
I worry more about what a power-failure can do to a ordinary hard disk than to an SSD. Last year I lost a 1TB disk of my SAN during the power outage here in Amsterdam, while the connected backup Samsung 500GB SSD was recovered by e2fsck with flying colors.

So much about fearing about losing an investment and addressing your questions.

1. Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 trims weekly with a script run by cron. It is here:

> $ cat /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim

2. I am temped to say No but that is my opinion. I found a nice quote on Lifehacker.com that supports my first paragraph: "*An SSD drive is a worthwhile investment, but like any storage device, it can fail. In fact, failing isn't that uncommon. As with your spinning drives, you should always set up a good backup solution, and you can do plenty to take full advantage of your SSD, but you can also take steps to maximize your SSD's lifespan.*".
   The website then offers tips that you asked for:
   (http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd)

About Swap to an USB stick. Interesting.
I have not seen it before, have seen articles that report success though. Still, I don't see the advantage, I expect performance degradation unless your system has plenty of RAM and don't have many memory intensive applications running, then swapping will not occur.

Please be aware temporary unmount swap is not an option. The swap partition is not mounted, swap is either on or off (use **gparted**). You must instruct the system to turn swap off, so it can check if anything is swapped out. If so, you must close programs until the RAM is not full anymore.

I hope this was helpfull.

Comment: I was so interested that I tried hibernating to USB. Indeed it works but as  stated it took about 30 seconds longer to startup my system.  Not shocking, but enough to prefer it over "regular" hibernation.

Comment: With SSD, Ubuntu boots so fast that I do not find hibernation worthwhile. Resolving one hassle is more lost time than saved from a years worth of reboots. Or I am not sure it is even any faster using hibernation.

Comment: @oldfred The idea behind hibernate in my case is: I'm a developer and usually I'd like to keep everything as it is while my computer is off. I don't worry about how fast my computer will boot up.

Comment: I understand the thought, but hope you (auto)save open files before you hibernate.